# accessing Priority form via REST API returns 404 form not ready

Tags: priority-web-sdk

I did all configuration need as I read on priority SDK portal and other StackOverflow resources to use rest api:

1. Installed License.
2. created api user name.
3. in forms for api/limited license I pulled the releveant forms and checked the API coulmn.

Yet I get:

```html
{
"error": {
"code": "400",
"message": "מסך DOCUMENTS_p אינו מוכן.",
"target": "",
"details": {},
"innererror": {}
}
}
```

What else needs to be done in priority for this to work.
I read in some answer to restrt IIS but that didn't work either.

Sami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Priority side error.
The form in Priority is malfunctioning and not compiled. The Priority implementer / programmer should run the *Prepare Form* on this `DOCUMENTS_p`, and see if it completes or has errors.